# Can you safely read utf8 and latin1 files with a naïve try-except block?

Tags: python, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I believe that any valid latin1 character will either be interpreted correctly by Python's utf8 encoder or throw an error. I, therefore, claim that if you work with only either utf8 files or latin1 files, you can safely write the following code to read those files, without ending up with [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```py
from pathlib import Path

def read_utf8_or_latin1_text(path: Path, args, kwargs):
    try:
        return path.read_text(encoding="utf-8")
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return path.read_text(encoding="latin1")
```

I tested this hypothesis out on [this large character data set](https://github.com/bits/UTF-8-Unicode-Test-Documents/blob/master/UTF-8_sequence_unseparated/utf8_sequence_0-0x10ffff_including-unassigned_including-unprintable-asis_unseparated.txt) and found that it holds up to scrutiny. Is this always the case?

#### Input:

```py
import requests

insanely_many_characters = requests.get(
    "https://github.com/bits/UTF-8-Unicode-Test-Documents/raw/master/UTF-8_sequence_unseparated/utf8_sequence_0-0x10ffff_including-unassigned_including-unprintable-asis_unseparated.txt"
).text


print(
    f"\n=== test {len(insanely_many_characters)} utf-8 characters for same-same misinterpretations ==="
)
for char in insanely_many_characters:
    if (x := char.encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")) != char:
        print(char, x)


print(
    f"\n=== test {len(insanely_many_characters)} latin1 characters for same-same misinterpretations ==="
)
latinable = []
nr = 0
for char in insanely_many_characters:
    try:
        if (x := char.encode("latin1").decode("latin1")) != char:
            print(char, x)
        latinable.append(char)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        nr += 1
if nr:
    print(f"{nr} characters not in latin1 set")

print('found the following valid latin1 characters: """\n' + "".join(latinable) + '\n"""')

print(
    f"\n=== test {len(latinable)} latin1 characters for utf-8 Mojibake ==="
)
for char in latinable:
    try:
        if (x := char.encode("latin1").decode("utf-8")) != char:
            print(char, x)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
```

#### Output:

```
=== test 1111998 utf-8 characters for same-same misinterpretations ===

=== test 1111998 latin1 characters for same-same misinterpretations ===
1111742 characters not in latin1 set
found the following latin1 characters: """
    
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ
"""

=== test 256 latin1 characters for utf-8 Mojibake ===
```

### Addendum:

I see I totally forgot to test for sequences of latin1 characters, and only tested for individual characters. By adding this test:

```py
print(
    f"\n=== test {len(latinable)} latin1 sequences wrongly interoperable by utf-8 ==="
)
for char1 in latinable:
    for char2 in latinable:
        try:
            if (x := (char1 + char2).encode("latin1").decode("utf-8")) != char1 + char2:
                print(char1 + char2, x)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
```

I ended up generating many utf-8 Mojibake (1920 instances in total), which is a counterexample to my hypothesis!:

```
=== test 256 latin1 sequences wrongly interoperable by utf-8 ===
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â 
Â   
Â¡ ¡

 ⋮
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrect. The `latin-1` encoding is a 1-1 mapping for every byte. It is wholly possible for validly encoded `latin-1` to, by coincidence, contain bytes that decode to a different UTF-8 character. The odds of such a thing occurring decrease the more non-ASCII characters are present in the data, but it can occur.

Your test isn't finding these cases, because, by definition, it would take at least two characters encoded to latin-1 to produce a valid, but mismatched, encoding of a single character in UTF-8 (non-ASCII encoded to UTF-8 is always 2-4 bytes in length, never just one byte; ASCII encodes the same in both latin-1 and UTF-8). Since you only tested encoding a single character a latin-1, it's impossible for it to produce a legal UTF-8 representation, but many pairs (or triples, or quads) of latin-1 characters above the ASCII range will coincidentally produce legal UTF-8 bytes. They may make for total garbage, but they'll decode validly.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, there are valid Latin-1 sequences which are also valid UTF-8 sequences. In practice, these are very unlikely in any real-world textual data.

You can easily create a table of the possible combinations; here is a sample for tasting.

```
>>> for x in "\u00a0\u00a1\u00a2\u00ff\u1234\U00012345":
...   print(x.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'))
... 
Â 
Â¡
Â¢
Ã¿
á´
ð
```

(There are some whitespace characters after `ð`.)

An important corner case may be files which contain [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake); it is pretty much impossible to devise a heuristic which would work correctly in the face of all the aspects of human <del>idiocy</del> ingenuity.  If you have mixed Latin-1 with  occasional mÃ¶jibÃ¤kÃ© from UTF-8, a naïve algorithm would conclude that the entire file must be Latin-1. (On the other hand, if the entire file is afflicted, it will actually solve the problem for you.)

Comment: That makes sense thanks, I had a scan through all the Mojibake producing sequence-of-two-latin1-characters, and nothing looks like characters that would for instance naturally occur in an English (or latin language) and numeric type text file such as a typical csv file. It's obviously still possible, but might be good enough for things like English/numeric csv files or English/numeric JSON files (if you know your source data well enough).

Comment: @SimonStreicher: A common solution to this on Windows is to use the `utf-8-sig` encoding when writing text data, rather than `utf-8`. It's non-standard (BOMs are for UTF-16 and UTF-32 to indicate endianness, which doesn't apply to UTF-8), but it's helpful for sniffing the file-type directly (reading just three bytes to check for the UTF-8 equivalent of a BOM) without needing to heuristically determine if it's UTF-8. Most Windows (or at least, Microsoft) applications recognize and accept (and can produce) a UTF-8 BOM; support is spottier on the UNIX-like side.

Comment: Using a BOM on Unix is often frowned upon because it causes interoperability problems - a text file should simply contain text, no metadata. On many systems UTF-8 is quite ubiquitous, and so there are few reasons to explicitly mark anything as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, our problem is with files we don't have control over. On writing, we use `utf-8` (unless tailored). We aggregate and merge (and transform) data from various legacy systems and have tools for our non-devs to use directly at clients. File encoding is just one of those problems that pop up frequently and it's hard to understand for a non-dev (and also hard to detect and circumvent). I'm thinking of adding an option `encoding="auto"` and then adding a few of these heuristics to ensure a likely good encoder ⊂ {`utf-8`, `latin1`} (in 4 years I've only seen `utf-8`/`latin1` at clients)

Answer (score 3):

Your initial assumption is right: if a file that can only be utf-8 of latin1 encoded cannot be read as utf-8, then it is latin1 encoded. The fact is that any sequence of bytes can be decoded as latin1 because there the latin1 encoding is a bijection between the 256 possible bytes and the unicode characters with code point in the [0;256[ range.

But your test if quite different. You load a valid utf-8 encoded file into unicode characters and then test which **unicode** characters exist in latin1 and find that only the 256 first are.

Said differently the question and the code areonly loosely related...

Comment: I agree that the tests are incomplete for several reasons. I think finding 256 latin1 characters isn't the fault (since it is documented as only having 256 characters and it got me to that set), it is in not testing sequences of latin1 characters for utf-8 Mojibake (and therefore not finding any counterexamples).

Comment: `The fact is that any sequence of bytes can be decoded as latin1` is a good theoretical disprove of my hypotheses, thanks. Since that means that any valid utf-8 file could theoretically be a desired latin1 file.